# Why is this kind of sentence still officially accepted?

Tags: word-usage, word-order

I have just come across this textbook on English Language and Art. There appears the sentence

> Byline tells you who **is** the author of an article.

As I remember, we all accept that the correct sentence must be

> Byline tells you who the author of an article **is**.

Can you please explain?

[image]

Comment: Both seem correct. 

Comment: A full sentence would use an article: "The byline tells you ..." or "A byline tells you ..." and in conversational English it would be "The byline tells you who the author is."

Comment: What do you mean by “officially accepted”?  There _is_ no single central authority defining the English Language.  (Which is part of the reason for many of the questions here — and the multiplicity of answers!)  And where do you get “we all accept that…” from?

Comment: Please do not post pictures in questions. Not everyone can see them. Please type it out.

Comment: That sentence is very poor: A by-line tells you who the author of an article is.

Comment: The sentence is "However, the byline says it was written by Joe Jerome's opponent." That is perfectly standard English. No article is being omitted, as commented by others. The article just comes before the bolded and capitalized (for emphasis, not to indicate the start of a sentence) "BYLINE."

Comment: It's not a sentence. It's a word "byline", then a definition, "*tells you who is the author of an article*". For some reason, it is a verb phrase where it should be a noun, and that verb phrase has bad grammar. The second "however" is also a mistake, and overall the writing style is unprofessional. I would throw this book out.

Comment: I'd say it's a punctuation error. "Byline: tells you who is the author of an article" with a colon. Dictionaries normally use a different font instead, for the entity being defined.

Comment: Seems the same as "tells you who wrote the article" vs "tells you who the article was written by", which are both valid.

Comment: @eyeballfrog No, that is completely different. The difference between an active and a passive sentence is in no way comparable to _wh_-fronting in relative clauses.

Comment: @nigel222 Well, English doesn't have yellow rectangle grammar. I say the writer is allowed to arrange different pieces of text to make the point they want. If they want to. In this particular case, it's not really clear that it's two pieces of text and not one sentence.

Comment: "who is the author" instead of "who the author is" is ungrammatical, but not jarringly so. I think omitting "the" (if this is one sentence) is much worse than "who is"

Comment: @user253751 what is "yellow rectangle grammar?" I'm not a professional writer/editor/etc, just an interested reader, and am curious.

Comment: @CGCampbell Yellow rectangle grammar is the set of grammatical rules for what you can put in a yellow rectangle. English doesn't have any rules about yellow rectangles. You can put anything you want in a yellow rectangle. There's no rule saying it's one sentence, and there's no rule saying it's a headline followed by a definition.

Answer (score 14):

You are broadly right.  However, the thing in the box isn't a sentence.  It is a dictionary definition.

In a definition, you first have the the headword. It is often printed in bold.  There is then a phrase to explain the meaning of the headword.  This phrase is often a fragment. So the headword is "**Byline**", and the definition is "tells you who is the author of the article".

You are right that, that fragment would be better expressed as "tells you who the author of the article is".  The expression in the book is okay as a fragment, but would be wrong if you expanded this fragment to a full sentence.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: It seems to be about whether *who* acts as a subject or as a complement.

Comment: @KateBunting - neither do I, in fact I prefer it.

Comment: A second answer would be useful, then.

Comment: Please offer an example of expanding this fragment to this wrong sentence.

Answer (score 14):

— Who is the author of the article?
— The author of the article is Allan Allandale.

The answer tells us who the author of the article is.

— Who is the author of the article?
— Allan Allandale is the author of the article.

The answer tells us who is the author of the article.

---

“The author is X” and “X is the author” have approximately the same meaning. They have different emphasis, and in some cases only one is appropriate. But there are many cases where both are possible.

In the relative clause, the normal word order is:

1. the pronoun (“who”);
2. the subject, if the pronoun is not the subject;
3. the verb (“is”);
4. complements.

(There can be additional complications but they don't apply here.)

In “who is the author of the article”, the subject is “who”, so the verb comes immediately after it. After that, there is one complement (a [predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicative_expression)).

In “who the author of the article is”, the subject is “the author of the article”, so that comes before the verb. The pronoun “who” is a predicate. It's the only complement of the verb “is” so the clause ends with “is”.

---

In this context, in a direct clause, it is more idiomatic in this context to say “the author of the article is Allan Allandale”, because we want to express information about the author of the article. It is natural to make “the author of the article” the subject of the sentence.

This is still true in a relative clause. However, in a relative clause, it is a little awkward to have a long fragment between the pronoun and the verb. This compensates the default tendency to make “the author of the article” the subject of the sentence. Hence the sentence “… who is the author of the article” is about as idiomatic as “… who the author of the article is”. The meaning is the same, after all.

With a shorter phrase, there would be a more marked preference for using the same subject as with direct clause. “The byline tells you who the author is” is more idiomatic than “the byline tells you who is the author”. The second sentence isn't grammatically wrong, but it's a bit awkward.

Comment: Subject-auxiliary inversion with wh-clauses only happens in actual questions. This grammar is what signals that a phrase is a question, rather than a mere noun phrase. That phrase isn't a question, so worse than "not idiomatic", it's wrong.

Comment: @gotube I don't understand your comment. There is no inversion here: the subject comes before the verb. The auxiliary comes first only when it's the relative pronoun, which has to come first (or after a preposition in some cases, but the relative pronoun can't move further inside the relative clause).

Comment: In "*The answer tells us [who is the author of the article]*", the deeper structure of the bracketed part is: "*The author of the article is who*", where "the author of the article" is the subject, and "who" is the **subject complement**. If this clause is a question, then the subject and auxiliary invert, otherwise they don't. Regardless, "who" moves to the front. English doesn't allow using "who is..." as a noun phrase. It's always a question.

Comment: @gotube No, in “The answer tells us who is the author”, the deeper structure is “X [=who] is the author”, with _X_ as the subject. It’s in “The answer tells us who the author is” that the deeper structure is “the author is X [=who]”, with _X_ as complement. There is only _wh_-fronting, no subject-auxiliary inversion (that would have made it “*…tells us is who the author”). _Who_ prefers complement position, but not all interrogatives do; _whoever_, for example, is happy in both positions: “Bring whoever is your favourite” and “Bring whoever your favourite is” are both perfectly fine. →

Comment: → If you create a sentence where only one covariant of subject and subject complement is possible, this becomes even more clear, because relativising it the wrong way around will become completely impossible. For example, “Meet the absolute screwup which is my brother” and “Meet my brother who is an absolute screwup” are both fine, but “*Meet the absolute screwup which my brother is” and “*Meet my brother [who/which?] an absolute screwup is” are completely ungrammatical, because their deeper structures don’t correspond to their respective antecedents. In the latter case, the mismatch is →

Comment: → highlighted by the fact that the antecedent is a person and the embedded subject isn’t, so we can’t even figure out which relative pronoun to use.

Comment: @gotube Another example which just occurred to me: as a general, semantically bleached, existential or dummy pronoun, _it_ is usually prohibited from appearing in subject complement position; but as a pseudo-nominalised pronoun used in various contexts, it is not. One such context is playing tag – someone in the game is ‘it’ (the chaser). If you point at a group of children playing tag and say, “I don’t know who it is”, you don’t know the identity of a particular child; if you say, “I don’t know who is it”, you don’t know which child is currently the chaser in the game.

Comment: @gotube “English doesn't allow using "who is..." as a noun phrase”: I don't understand where you're getting this rule from. Consider this question: “Who is at the door?” Now turn it into reported speech: “Alice asks …” — how do you end that sentence?

Comment: You're right, "who is..." can be a noun phrase. I was talking about the context with "who" as a subject complement. In yours above, "who" is the subject because the subject complement isn't a noun at all. If the grammar you're claiming were correct, we should expect a sentence like "*I know who **is** he*" to at least appear on the radar, but [it doesn't](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Tell+us+who+is+he%2CTell+us+who+he+is&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019). And I separately assert as a native speaker, that “*The answer tells us who **is** the author*” is bad grammar.

Comment: @gotube In “… who is the author”, “the author“ is the subject. With a pronoun as the complement, in modern English, that would be “I know who is him”, but I'm having trouble finding a natural context where both the subject and the complement of *be* can be pronouns outside of set phrases such as “that's him” where the subject can't be a relative pronoun.

Comment: @gotube “I separately assert as a native speaker, that (…) is bad grammar.” Being a native speaker gives you authority to assert that it's unidiomatic, but not that it's bad grammar. It's perfectly good grammar, but this thread shows that the idiomaticity varies between speakers. That's about the semantic asymmetry of “X is Y” vs “Y is X”, not about grammar.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I take your point about the difference between "unidiomatic" and "ungrammatical". I'm OK with not agreeing that it applies in this case. I appreciate the dialogue too.

Answer (score 12):

At the risk of upsetting the community: it is a common misconception that there are statutes governing English grammar, or some regulating authority which is mandated to determine what is "correct".

That is far from being the case.

The best we have is conventions, familiarity due to common-usage, and occasionally taboos.

So while "who is the author" is jarring, and would probably be avoided by any author or editor with any veneer of sophistication, it is inappropriate to refer to "officially accepted".

Now it might be that certain words or phrases are not acceptable in- for example- a court, or should be avoided because of their ambiguity, or would cause a well-schooled reader to look carefully at their context. I would suggest that the word "sanctioned" falls into that category, particularly if the context is a letter from a layman to a lawyer.

The context of the current example is an informal "scrapbook-style" guide, typeset in something close to the much-derided Comic Sans, and probably intended for teenagers. The advice might or might not be good, but don't let it bother you.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the "officially accepted" aspect.  The font is called [Set fire to the rain](http://www.identifont.com/list?2+set%20fire%20to%20the%20rain+0.2+2JLG+1+3SMI+1)

Comment: @JamesK I was wondering about it, but had limited time and definitely didn't want to be more verbose than necessary in something which could have been contentious.

Comment: "while "who is the author" is jarring"  - not to everyone. Maybe a difference between British-English and US-English?

Comment: @MikeB Maybe, maybe not. That in part is my point.

Comment: It sounds maybe, slightly atypical but highly acceptable, to me -- 40 yo native American English speaker and a prolific novel reader until about 20. I'm honestly shocked so many people seem to dislike it.

Comment: Younger (20s) native speaker here; it does feel *strange* but not *infelicitous*. It feels almost like it would be obligatory to contract to "who's" due to some kind of prosodic concern, or perhaps that moving the "is" up would have to be motivated by intending a contraction to begin with, but it still "checks out" syntactically.

Comment: @UnrelatedString There's always the possibility that it was intended to be "simple English" in keeping with the overall tenor of the guide as suggested by its typesetting and layout. Alternatively that it is a (misguided IMO) attempt to simplify English by showing that the question "who is the..." can be answered by prefixing it with "tells you", hence "tells you who is the...". So again: context is important.